# Equivalence on pseudocompactness.

Tags: general-topology

Does someone know a reference or proof of the following equivalence on pseudocompactness?

> A completely regular space $X$ is pseudocompact if, and only if, every non empty $G_\delta$ set in $\beta X$ meets $X$, where $\beta X$ is the Stone-Čech compactification of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is Theorem $28$ of Edwin Hewitt, ‘Rings of real-valued continuous functions. I’, *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **64** (1948), 45-99 , which is freely available [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1948-064-01/S0002-9947-1948-0026239-9/). The theorem is on p. $68$.